# Material Design Lite Menu dynamically ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, material-design-lite

I am trying to achieve the menu features in MDL. It is working well statically as shown in the code below.

```
<button id="demo-menu-lower-left"
    class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
    <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
for="demo-menu-lower-left">
   <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
   <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
   <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
   <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>
```

I am implementing the above code using Angular's ng-repeat as it will repeat the ID of the button with the id of the ng-repeat. After the repeat, the menu is not being able to dropdown. What am i missing here? The code below is with the ng-repeat which doesn't work

```
<div ng-repeat="product in vm.products">

<button id="{{product._id}}"
    class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
    <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
</button>

<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
for="{{product._id}}">
   <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
   <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
   <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
   <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you inspect the dom and see, what is the button id value and for value in the ul -> {{product._id}}?

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury they are a random generated id from the database such as 56fdf88b8dca55a01b36674f

Comment: Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/xjdjjjrz/

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury thank you! Maybe i just did a spelling mistake somewhere in my code. it works now. Thanks! Do create an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/xjdjjjrz

```
<div ng-repeat="product in vm.products">
  <button id="{{product._id}}-{{$index}}"
      class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
      <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
  </button>
  <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
  for="{{product._id}}-{{$index}}">
     <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
     <li class="mdl-menu__item mdl-menu__item--full-bleed-divider">Another Action</li>
     <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
     <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```